# O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Estou criando um programa que armazena os perfis de todos os professores online atualmente em uma lista e depois exibe os 3 primeiros em uma *label* (onde um botão avança exibindo os próximos 3 online), porém quando vou atribuir os valores da lista em uma *label* ele gera a seguinte exceção:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.'

Código do programa:

```
Consultar consultar = new Consultar();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = null;
        SqlDataReader dr2 = null;
        List<string> nome = new List<string>();
        List<byte[]> imagem = new List<byte[]>();
        List<string> disciplina = new List<string>();
        private int i = 0;
        public ProfessoresOn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dr1 = consultar.PesquisaProfOnline();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                nome.Add(dr1["NOME_PROFESSOR"].ToString());
                imagem.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dr1["FOTO_PROFESSOR"].ToString()));
                dr2 = consultar.PesquisaDisciplinaProf(dr1["IDPROFESSOR"].ToString());
                while (dr2.Read())
                {
                    disciplina.Add(dr2["NOME_DISCIPLINA"].ToString());
                }
            }
            lblnome1.Content = nome[i];// O erro ocorre nesta linha
            lblnome2.Content = nome[i++];
            lblnome3.Content = nome[i+2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código tem pelo menos dois problemas, um que não é tão aparente que está incrementando a variável `i` (em `i++`), e não parece que quer isto porque pularia um. Mas na verdade está bem esquisito, porque esse código nas últimas três linhas, a primeira sempre valerá 0, a segunda sempre valerá 1 e a terceira sempre valerá 3 (acho que queria que fosse 2), então essa variável nem faz sentido.

Mas o erro já ocorre logo de cara, porque a coleção `nome` neste caso tem zero elementos, e por isso dá o erro, então acho que nem entrou no laço por não ter nada no banco de dados. Note que por esse código teria que sempre ter pelo menos 3 itens no banco de dados.

A solução deve ser colocar essa execução condicionalmente. Se tiver nenhum elemento deve informar que não tem nada e não tentar pegar o dado. Já para o segundo e terceiro elementos precisa ver no seu requisito o que deve fazer, apresentar erro ou simplesmente considerar isso em branco ou fazer outra ação.

Pela descrição parece que isto aconteça depois de algum ter dado certo (a pergunta não deixa claro que isto é um laço mais geral), e parece que tem um outro problema de lógica aí, mas não posso fazer mais por não ter nada na pergunta que o permita.

E parece que tem uma falha grave no uso do `SqlDataReader` em que pelo menos uma exceção o deixa pendurado, mas quem sabe até nem esteja o encerrando-o em condições normais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ss posso ver onde errei agr. Muito obrigado